# Implications of using Flow.asLiveData()

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

Our team recently adopted Kotlin Flow in our Android projects.

As far as I understand one of the drawbacks of flows in Android is that it is not LifeCycleAware. This is why we keep using LiveData to link view states and data to our views. An easy way to use both, is to let our Room Queries return Flows. This way as soon as our data is transformed, and we want to link it to views, we can use the asLiveData() function.

Now my question:
Something with always casting to liveData feels not right to me. Is this the right way? does casting to LiveData have implications? And aren't we better using a duplicate Room query that returns a liveData version?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

One drawback is that it introduces a platform dependency on Android where you use it (for ex: ViewModels).

But you could instead use `StateFlows` or `SharedFlows` and when you consume it you can tie the subscription to the lifecycle, making it lifecycle-aware. So this way the Publisher/Flow isn't lifecycle-aware, but your Observer/Subscriber is.

A good article about this: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda